# How to deploy Ruby app on an existing LAMP server, without messing up Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, virtualhost, lamp, openproject

I am trying to install OpenProject on a CentOS 7 VPS that already has several PHP/MySQL websites and Apache on it.

OpenProject has an install/configuration script that you run with:

sudo openproject configure

The script has an option to 'Install apache2 server' or 'Skip' and do it manually. The assumption seems to be that you install on a empty server. I can't find clear instructions anywhere how to configure an existing Apache installation to access the OpenProject scripts.

When I 'Skip' apache2 installation, the result of 'sudo openproject run check' is a 'Web server is NOT running' error, even though Apache is up and running on my server.

Should I pick option 'Install apache2 server'? Would it wipe/reconfigure/mess up my existing Apache configuration?

Or what are manual steps to configure Apache to access/run a Ruby app like OpenProject from a subfolder like mywebsite.com/openproject ?

I looked into installing Phusion Passenger without Apache, but it looks like it always (?) comes packaged with Apache and could still potentially conflict with an existing Apache configuration - again, can't find info for this case.

Answer (score 0):

What I have found out since January 20, if your Apache is configured via cPanel/WHM, use the following instructions to install Passenger:

https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/using-passenger-cpanel-centos-7/

Make sure you have EasyApache4:

ls /etc/cpanel/ea4/is_ea4

Then add the mod_passenger option plus supporting packages into your EasyApache 4 configuration:

yum -y update; yum -y install ea-ruby24-mod_passenger ea-ruby24-ruby-devel ea-apache24-devel

There is one more item we need in order to install Ruby applications easily:

scl enable ea-ruby24 'gem install bundle'

Confirm that mod_passenger, the connector to Apache, was installed properly:

httpd -M | grep passenger

Make sure that Passenger itself is set up and working:

scl enable ea-ruby24 'passenger-config validate-install'

Then you have to use Application Manager in cPanel to configure your Virtual Host and "deploy" your Ruby app - this still didn't work for me, but that is probably another issue.

If Application Manager does not show up in cPanel, you may have to activate it for your account via WHM.